How to pass item from list that is being sorted to lambda that is used as the key function used for the sorting?
I have a function that evaluates some parameters of the first argument it receives (here item):
def item_fitness(
    item,
    fitness_criterion1,
    fitness_criterion2
    ) -> int:
    ...
    return val

It does not matter what it actually does. All that matters is that it takes fitness_criterion1 and fitness_criterion2 in order to check the item's parameters  and returns some fitness score.
I would like to use the function as the sorting function in sorted() like this:
def some_function(items, crit1, crit2):
    items = sorted(
        items,
        key=lambda item, crit1, crit2: item_fitness(
            item,
            crit1,
            crit2
        ),
        reverse=True
    )

    # Do something with the sorted items

    return something

where item is taken from items (the actual list of item instances that is being sorted()).
How would I do that? The function is also called elsewhere with specific elements from items.

The key function can access crit1 and crit2 as non-local variables; key=lambda item: item_fitness(item, crit1, crit2) should suffice.

the key callable function takes as input only the element from the iterable. Try to see what happens with  key=lambda item, crit1=crit1, crit2=crit2: and then read the previous comment of chepner for a further simplification

Try this:
def item_fitness(
        item,
        fitness_criterion1,
        fitness_criterion2
) -> int:
    # ...
    return "val"


def some_function(items, crit1, crit2):
    items = sorted(
        items,
        key=lambda item: item_fitness(
            item,
            crit1,
            crit2
        ),
        reverse=True
    )

    # Do something with the sorted items
    return "something"

print(some_function([1, 2, 3], "crit1", "crit2"))  # something


How exactly is this working? And why did you convert val to just a string?

@rbaleksandar because val is undefined in your code, probably. It might help to provide a working reproducible example with your questions in the future.

@rbaleksandar the criterions are passed as string to your function item_fitness. Up to you to do what you want with them. The item is also passed. Up to you also to return the value you want. I converted it to string just to test this code in my editor

crit1 and crit2 are free variables in the function defined by the lambda expression. Their lookup devolves to the closest enclosing scope, namely that of some_function, where the parameters crit1 and crit2 are local variables.

Function given to key may only accept a single argument.
You can use functool.partial to create a new function with some of the arguments pre-applied.
from functools import partial

def some_function(items, crit1, crit2):
    items = sorted(
        items,
        key=partial(item_fitness, fitness_criterion1 = crit1, fitness_criterion2=crit2),
        reverse=True
    )


Doesn't partial() require as a first argument the function it is representing? I already tried it (partial(item_fitness, fitness_criterion1=crit1, fitness_criterion2=crit2)) but I still get that the call requires 3 positional arguments.

@rbaleksandar You're right about missing function for the first argument, but it works for me with that added.
